# Where should I code the methods, mainForm or another class?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a MainForm which contains the UI handling and an object class where file names are to be passed on a method and create a list of these file names.

I have a method to compare these files, `compareFiles()`. I know I could just code that method inside the MainForm class, but is it more appropriate to contain that method on another class? What could be the advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Are you going to be using this functionality again, or in some other form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an utility class for methods that doesn't belong to objects or entities, and could be useful for any object or task inside your whole application

```
public class Utility
{
    public static void compareFiles() { ... }
}
```

As you can see.. methods inside this class should be "static", because you don't have to instantiate a object to usethis kind of method, you can simple use directly anywhere in your project:

```
Utility.compareFiles();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's my first time to encounter the utility class.. so can I pass objects to methods inside this class? And can it contain 2 or more methods?

Comment: Yes, can contain many methods. But always take care that methods here doesn't belong to any object, I'll give an example: CheckClientAccount(), that method should be on Client class, because will be useful just for clients, not Utility. Now: EncodeCharacters(), RemoveAccent(), CopyFile(), and these kind of "generic" stuff that could be used anywhere for any object (as the name says: Utility!) you could put there

Comment: Am I right with this: Pass the instantiated objects from object class, `fileA` and `fileB` to the UI/MainForm and then call `CompareFiles(fileA, fileB)` (of the utility class) .

Answer (score 1):

In your case, separating the CompareFiles to a separate method buys you a more modular code. Modular code is generally easier to understand, easier to manage and easier to debug. It also promotes re-use across applications. To go further, you may want to  think about Classes and not just separate methods. The object concept is the foundation of OO.

Comment: Thanks! Does this also mean I can code the method to a static class and just call the objects from an object class for that?

Comment: You can create a static class and use its static methods without creating an instance (object) first. However, static classes are not the norm in large applications.

Comment: static classes in C# doesn't matter much, they're just instantiable.. and it actually is good for utility class. You can check more there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Agree they are commonly used for utility vars and methods. However, some people tend to abuse their use :)